# VSCode doesn't split parentheses in JavaScript on indent

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, indentation

How can I avoid this type of formatting In VSCode?

```
if (
  /^(?=.*[a-z])[A-Za-z\d!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]{6,12}$/.test(
    value
  )
) {
  numberCondition++;
}
```

to

```
if (/^(?=.*[a-z])[A-Za-z\d!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]{6,12}$/.test(value)) {
  numberCondition++;
}
```

Comment: Souns like you just want to increase the default printWidth: open user settings and paste `"prettier.printWidth": 120,`

Comment: @ippi thanks its work

Comment: *"How can I avoid this type of formatting"* the best way is to not to write like this. `const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])[A-Za-z\d!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~]{6,12}$/; if (regex.test(value)) { ... }`.

Comment: thank for a tip @dfsq